# How to add the cmake compiler path(generator) to run the catkin_make command in ROS?

Tags: cmake, generator, ros

I am trying to work with the Robot Operating System (ROS Melodic) on Windows 10 system, following the procedure from the ROS website.

http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

When I try to create a workspace `(/catkin_ws/src)` and run the catkin_make, 
I run into different errors viz., `CMAKE_C_COMPILER, CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER paths`.

So I tried to run `cmake --help` to find the list of generators available, so as to give the aforementioned path of a compiler. This again creates new errors stating `No CMAKELists.txt found`.

I am a newbie to programming and I don't get any of these. 
Can anyone explain why we need this compiler path, generator, etc to build this workspace and how to run ROS successfully on Windows?

Thanks in advance for your support.

> C:\opt\catkin_ws>cmake -G "NMAKE Makefiles" CMake Error: Could not
>   create named generator NMAKE Makefiles
>
> C:\opt\catkin_ws>cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" CMake Error: CMake was
>   unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles". 
>   CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a
>   different build tool. CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build
>   program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not
>   set.  You probably need to select a different build tool. CMake Error:
>   CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage CMake Error:
>   CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_AR
>   was not found, please set to archive program.
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: The generator is called `"NMake Makefiles"`. Case matters. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#manual:cmake-generators(7) for a list of supported generators on Windows.

Comment: C:\opt\catkin_ws>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"
    CMake Error: Error: generator : NMake Makefiles
    Does not match the generator used previously: MSYS MakefilesEither remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.

Comment: Then please delete `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory. Do this always when you change something inside of `CMakeLists.txt`. Otherwise changes may not be assigned due to cache.

Comment: Now I get this error-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

Comment: Dumb question: Do you have a compiler installed? If it is Visual Studio: try to open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, clear the cache again and run the same commands again. Otherwise please state what compiler you are trying to use in the question.